# How to rearrange the li id between two UL in sortable?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-ui

**NOTE : UPDATED QUESTION**

Below is the HTML,

```
 <ul id="sortable1" class="connectedSortable">
  <li id="listItem_1">test1</li>
  <li id="listItem_2">test2</li>
  <li id="listItem_3">test3</li>
 </ul>
```

and second UL is like ,

```
 <ul id="sortable2" class="connectedSortable">
  <li id="secondlistItem_1">second test1</li>
  <li id="secondlistItem_2">second test2</li>
  <li id="secondlistItem_3">second test3</li>
 </ul>
```

jquery sortable code is like,

```
jQuery(function() {
    jQuery( "#sortable1, #sortable2" ).sortable({
        connectWith: ".connectedSortable",
    update : function () { 

        jQuery.post(BASE_URL+"tabs/index", jQuery('#sortable1').sortable('serialize'),
            function(data) {
               //alert(data);         
            });                           
    }
    }).disableSelection();   
});
```

I call ajax function on update event and pass all li position by using serialize.so that i can able to update li position easily. But when we place from second UL li to  first UL LI,needed to update the newly appended LI with new id and position before call update event.

How can i rearrange the li id with newly appended li from `sortable2` or from itself once user changed LI?

For example user make some changes between two UL like,

```
 <ul id="sortable1" class="connectedSortable">
  <li id="secondlistItem_1">second test1</li>
  <li id="listItem_1">test1</li>
  <li id="listItem_3">test3</li>
 </ul>
```

above UL should rearrange the li id like

```
 <ul id="sortable1" class="connectedSortable">
  <li id="listItem_1">second test1</li>
  <li id="listItem_2">test1</li>
  <li id="listItem_3">test3</li>
 </ul>
```

Is it possible to do that in `receive` event? Kindly help me on this

Comment: Should "listeItem_" and "secondlistItem_" be automaticaly named or do you want it to be exactly what you want?

Comment: @Boris Actually i need to update the both UL li position in DB , I am using jQuery('#sortable1').sortable('serialize') to pass the li position to my ajax function.before serialize,need to rearrange the LI id

Answer (score 0):

I am using the following way to re generate my ul li id,

```
jQuery(function() { 
    jQuery( "#sortable1, #sortable2" ).sortable({
        connectWith: ".connectedSortable",
        receive : function(event, ui){
           jQuery('#sortable1 li').each(function(index) {
                jQuery(this).attr('id','listItem_'+parseInt(index+1));
                console.log(index + ': ' + jQuery(this).attr('id'));
            });        
           jQuery('#sortable2 li').each(function(index) {
                jQuery(this).attr('id','secondlistItem_'+parseInt(index+1));
                console.log(index + ': ' + jQuery(this).attr('id'));
            })            
        },
        update : function () {

           var order1 = jQuery('#sortable1').sortable('serialize'); 
            jQuery.post(BASE_URL+"appbuilder/tabs/index", jQuery('#sortable1').sortable('serialize'),
                function(data) {
                       console.log(data);
                });       
            jQuery.post(BASE_URL+"appbuilder/tabs/index", jQuery('#sortable2').sortable('serialize'),
                function(data) {
                            console.log(data);
                });                    
        }
    }).disableSelection();   
});
```